# PHP loop according to amount of items in array

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to write a short script that will query my mysql db, and according to the amount of results (dynamic) i want the script on each segment.

For example, `$arr` is a result of a `mysql_fetch_array` and it has 872 items, I want to run my function 9 times, 1 for each 100 items and the last one for 72 items.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want each segment you loop over to be a maximum of 100 items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a `for` loop with an incrementor that increments by 100. You can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) to get the concerned rows on each loop.

```
$dbRows = resultsFromDB();

for($i = 0; $i < count($dbRows); $i+=100) {
  $concernedRows = array_slice($dbRows, $i, 100);

  mySuperFunction($concernedRows);
}
```

Comment: Placing count() function in for condition slows down the execution, because it counts the items every loop pass.

Comment: @Ondřej Mirtes: **No it doesn't.** `count()` doesn't loop through the elements to count, it simply accesses a property of the `zend_hash`. I invite you to browse around the PHP source; specifically at [`zend_hash_num_elements()`](http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_hash.c) and [`PHP_FUNCTION(count)`](http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/array.c). The number of items in an PHP Array (Zend Hash) is automatically updated on insertion/deletion. An array with 1,000,000 elements takes as long as an empty array to count.

Comment: I was talking about this: http://www.codeforest.net/php-mythbusters-count-inside-for-loop-is-slow

Comment: @Ondřej Mirtes: He's wrong. Try it out yourself and check the PHP source. Any contributor will tell you that the only overhead of calling `count()` versus storing the result in a variable is the function call. That's it. `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
$length = count($arr);

for ($i = 0; $i < ceil($length / 100); $i++) {

}
```

If I understood.

Comment: For some reason, the loop runs only 108 times ($i = 108 after the loop ends) and ``count($arr) = 2700``

Comment: @Or W: *"only"*? By your specification, an array of 2700 items should only run your function 27 times, not 108 times.

Comment: @Or W, maybe show the rest of the code you implemented it in. Try running `$length = 2700; echo ceil($length / 100);`. Should output `27`